# Dual Boot System (Encrypted with veracrypt) - Windows 10 and Ubuntu (whatever most recent version)

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

Just for background:
Im a windows user but i want to switch to linux/ubuntu ASAP.
Microsoft has started sueing german citizens for buying cheap microsoft in official stores (like walmart). Our public prosecutors office seems to have run out of actual criminals to persecute and therefore decided to follow along. Ridiculous.

However, back to topic.
Im running windows 10 on Drive 1 and I want to add Ubuntu on Drive 2.
I want my OS drive fully encrypted. My OS has been for the past 8 years or so and it will stay that way.

So Win10 drive is already encrypted. When I did encrypt it a few months ago (built a new system) I chose "only one OS", since veracrypt already seems to offer dual boot support, even explicitely offering Windows and Linux pairing in the options.

So, how do I proceed now?
Can I just boot my ubuntu setup from stick, install ubuntu on drive 2, then run veracrypt, chose "encrypt OS..." with dual boot option Win + Linux, encrypt it, restart the machine and then find myself in a pre boot environment asking me which OS/drive to boot from?

Would be awesome, but if things are more complicated, please enlighten me on how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: It's complicated only due to your requirement to use Veracrypt instead of the encryption application included in the Ubuntu installer. Since Ubuntu cannot distribute Veracrypt (the FSF considers [their license non-free](https://mirror.fsf.org/hyperbola/gnu-plus-linux-libre/testing/blacklist/blacklist.txt)), few here will have experience with that software. Everything else seems quite ordinary. Were I in your shoes, I would try installing Ubuntu un-encrypted and with plain default first to see what success looks like, then again with installer-provided encryption and other fancies.

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as wheat ever is most recent. An actual version is needed.